# Ambiguous method from inheritance when using a CRTP pattern

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, crtp, ambiguous

I am defining a `DoubleWrapper` class inheriting from two CRTP base classes, `Ratioable` and `Divable`, that both define `operator/()`, with different signatures:

```
T operator/(double const& scalar) const { return T(this->underlying().get() / scalar); }
double operator/(T const& other) const { return this->underlying().get() / other.get(); }
```

They differ both by return type and parameter type. However compiler is complaining about operator/() being ambiguous. Note that the constructor is explicit so there is no ambiguous conversion from double to DoubleWrapper.

- On Visual Studio 2017 it is compiling and running fine however I get a tooltip in the code "more than one operator "/" matches those operands: (...)" at the place of use. If I rename the operator to make it a regular method (`divide`(...)), I get a compile error :

error C2385: ambiguous access of 'divide'
note: could be the 'divide' in base 'Divable'
note: or could be the 'divide' in base 'Ratioable'

- G++ 6.2 gives me a compile error even with the operator version:

  error: request for member ‘operator/’ is ambiguous
  double b  = a / a;
                ^
  note: candidates are: double Ratioable::operator/(const T&) const [with T = DoubleWrapper]
  double operator/(T const& val) const { return this->underlying().get() / val.get(); }
       ^~~~~~~~
  note:                 T Divable::operator/(const double&) const [with T = DoubleWrapper]
  T operator/(double const& val) const { return T(this->underlying().get()/ val); }
  ^~~~~~~~

C++ allows methods with the same name as long as they have different signatures. Where is the ambiguity coming from ?

Test code:

```
    DoubleWrapper a(10.);
    double b  = a / (a/2.); // Both operator/ should be called. I would expect b value to be 2.
```

Source code:

```
    /* Curiously Recurring Template Pattern  */
template <typename T, template<typename> class crtpType>
struct crtp
{
    T& underlying() { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }
    T const& underlying() const { return static_cast<T const&>(*this); }
};

/* Inheriting class can be divided by a scalar */
template<typename T>
struct Divable : crtp<T, Divable>
{
    T operator/(double const& scalar) const { return T(this->underlying().get() / scalar); }
};

/* Inheriting class can be divided by itself */
template<typename T>
struct Ratioable : crtp<T, Ratioable>
{
    double operator/(T const& other) const { return this->underlying().get() / other.get(); }
};

struct DoubleWrapper : 
    public Divable<DoubleWrapper>, 
    public Ratioable<DoubleWrapper>
{
    explicit DoubleWrapper(double val) : val_(val) {}

    double get() const { return val_; }

private:
    double val_;
};
```

Comment: `using Divable<DoubleWrapper>::operator/;using Ratioable<DoubleWrapper>::operator/;` should solve your issue.

Comment: Indeed, it does, thank you. The bigger problem from which I abstracted that issue is that I would like to define types inheriting from traits such as Divable and Ratioable (and many more, like Addable, Multable etc.). I can't expect user of that code to add "using xxx" statements whenever adding a certain inherited trait combination to their types. Do you see any other way around it? Do you know why that ambiguity is not resolved by the compiler on its own in that particular case? What language feature prohibits that resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name resolution is done before overload resolution.

There are no `operator/` in `DoubleWrapper` so the compiler goes looking for `operator/` in it's base classes and finds one in both making the name ambiguous (and no overload resolution takes place).

You may resolve name resolution with `using`:

```
struct DoubleWrapper : 
    public Divable<DoubleWrapper>, 
    public Ratioable<DoubleWrapper>
{
    using Divable<DoubleWrapper>::operator/;
    using Ratioable<DoubleWrapper>::operator/;

    explicit DoubleWrapper(double val) : val_(val) {}

    double get() const { return val_; }

private:
    double val_;
};
```

Interesting reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_(C++)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup