# 2 ways of resolving ambigous inheritance of virtual method

Tags: c++, inheritance

Following code is from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2250?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2250)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=vs-2019), I copied the code here to avoid doing my own sample, basically I'm having this problem in my project.

```
struct V {
   virtual void vf();
};

struct A : virtual V {
   void vf() override;
};

struct B : virtual V {
   void vf() override;
};

struct D : A, B {
   // Uncomment the following line to resolve.
   // void vf() override;
};
```

I took a look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912649/ambiguous-method-from-inheritance-when-using-a-crtp-pattern) where the suggestion is to use `using` directive to resolve ambiguous symbol.

That suggestion doesn't work for this sample, instead to resolve the problem we should explicitly override base methods in derived class.

I would like to avoid explicitly override in derived class, so the question is, why cant this be resolved with `using` directive as suggested in SO link above, instead of overriding? for example:

```
struct D : A, B {
   using A::vf(); // not going to work
};
```

The reason why to avoid explicit override is to make use of method code in one of the base classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I think you **have** to give an explicit override to resolve the ambiguity! However, it would be an extremely trivial override:

```cpp
struct D : A, B {
    // Uncomment the following line to resolve.
    void vf() override { A::vf(); }
};
```

This will just call the `A` base class whenever `D::vf()` is called! Thus, in accordance with your last sentence, there is no problem, as the *"method code in one of the base class"* is used (but you have to specify which base class).

Comment: Just as a note: I am not normally in the habit of using the phrase, "I think" in answers: in this case what I meant was that, ***to my knowledge***, there is no way to avoid such an override. However, I would be very interested to see if any of the seriously decent `c++` coders on this forum can come up with a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

`using` simply resolves which method you mean to call, in this case.
`D` still needs to be a complete object and must have a final overrider for `vf` regardless of resolve helpers.
If `vf` was **not** implemented in the base class, then `using` would suffice, as the type is complete and all you need to do is resolve the correct call.

Comment: Additional note: `vf()` is virtual, so it is required to disambiguate what implementation of `vf()` ends up in the vtable of `D`. A directive like `using` that is not designed to impact the vtable cannot do the trick.